# Popup in Mapbox Studio

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

Are popup markers supported in Mapbox Studio?

I inherited a project which uses earlier versions of Mapbox. Today, a marketing personnel asked me because she cannot update the data that is being shown in our website. It seems that it is because the old MapBox Editor has already been deprecated by last November 2016 (https://www.mapbox.com/blog/migrating-from-editor/).

The old maps they have has popup markers like this:

[image]

Is this supported in the new MapBox Studio? How will I be able to do this especially if **the popup content will be coming from the JSON datasets of the older project?**

Answer (score 3):

To enable pop-up, mapbox-gl-js should be used after creating a Style using your datasets in Mapbox Studio.

Please look at this 3 part tutorial series by Mapbox.

https://www.mapbox.com/help/studio-manual-tutorials/#add-points-to-a-map

https://www.mapbox.com/help/add-points-pt-3/